# How can i convert the List<string> to a dataset in the required format

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all i will read the required Content from an Excel sheet so that i will get the required data and i am saving that to  `List<String>` as follows

[image]

Now i would like to have my dataset in such a way that i would like to format in this way

[image]

Is it possible to do as per my requirement if so can any one help me..

Comment: This is graphical data, not list data. What are you attempting to do with the dataset? Do you have to store it somewhere, display it?

Comment: `List<String>` data is as shown in the first image what i required is i would like to frame the dataset as per the second image

Comment: Right, and that leads to my question. A dataset isn't used to displaying data. It's used for holding, sorting, filtering, cataloging and updating it. Your second image is a graph. Are you looking to display this graph on a webpage somewhere or is this dataset intended to be uploaded to a database?

Comment: That is a pivot or a cross tab. MS-Access TRANSFORM command can do that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208956(v=office.12).aspx  The word DataSet has a very specific meaning in .NET, namely, it is a common data container in ADO.NET. Your problem has nothing to do with DataSets per se.

Comment: I would also add that using a List<string> is the wrong type of collection for this type of data.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing natively that can do this for you in the .NET framework;  I'm not sure if anything exists in open source/third-party.  It wouldn't be extremely difficult to build a routine to convert the data in the format you like.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not coding it for you, but it is easy, if I understood your question well. Iterate the list while DateTime.TryParse returns true, so you get all column names (year, months). Then you have to do something custom for the description columns. For showing the float data do the same, iterate while Float.TryParse returns true...